# Call Java function from C# using extern modifier in .NET lbrary JNetCall

Tags: java, c#, .net

I download JNetCall library, and successfully runs example code. But when I tried to add my functionality, I had problems with it.

Java code:

```
private static void internalMethod(double n1) {
    System.out.println("InternalMethod " + n1);
}
```

C# code:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
private static extern void InternalMethod(double n1);
```

If i call C# function from constructor of C# interface i get this Java output:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
```

If i tried to call it not from constructor but from some where else, i get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: [500] System.Security.SecurityException: ECall methods must be packaged into a system module.
```

Comment: Add details on what you tried and what error you see / what doesn't work, otherwise it's a guess.